# query last 10 minus last 5 records in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
var q = models.Post.find().sort('date', -1).limit(10);
q.execFind(function(err, posts) {
    // previous 6 to 10th records needed.
});
```

The above will query the last 10 records. I can drop the first 5 from it:-

```
posts.splice(0, 4);
```

Go gain records 6th to 10th. But is there a direct method to query such set directly ? Like

```
var q = models.Post.find().sort('date', -1).limit(5 to 10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for

```
models.Post.find().skip(5).limit(5)
```

The following query worked for me with mongoose -- note that my schema is probably different from yours:

```
> Post.find().skip(5).limit(5).exec(function(err, p) { if (err) { console.log("error"); }; console.log(p); })
```